# Is there any way to rename hive table without losing its data?

Tags: database, hadoop, hive

I want to rename the tables that I have already created using hive. Is there any way to rename those tables without losing its data?

Comment: Why are you expecting the data to get lost? Nowhere in the docs does it say this: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-RenameTable

Comment: Thanks Hunter! I am new to hive and my previous attempts to rename hive tables somehow lead to data loss. The command pointed by you works fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this instead

```
ALTER TABLE database.table_to_rename rename to new_table_name;
```